# Proof analytic functions $f:\mathbb{C}_\infty \to \mathbb{C}_\infty$ are constant

Tags: complex-analysis

How can I prove that analytic functions defined $f: \mathbb{C}_\infty \to \mathbb{C}_\infty$ are constant? I know about Picard Little Theorem that states that entire functions in the complex are either constant or their image is the whole complex plane or the complex plane minus one point, but I don't understand how the addition of $\infty$ in the domain let me discard all these options. I have also thought about using the maximum modulus principle, so I can state that either $\lim_{z \to \infty} |f(z)| = +\infty$ or $\lim_{z \to \infty} |f(z)|$ doesn't exist. Would this be enought to state that I would have problems at the infinite?

Comment: Your notion of "analytic" allows the value infinity?  Then consider the linear fractional transfomations which map $\mathbb C_\infty$ bijectively onto itself.  For example $f(z) = 1/z$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $U = \{ z\in \Bbb{C},|z|<2\}$ and $\phi_j: U\to \Bbb{C}_\infty, \phi_1(z)=z,\phi_2(z)=1/z$.

Let $f(z) = 1/z$. Would you mind telling us how do we check if it is analytic $\Bbb{C}_\infty\to \Bbb{C}_\infty$ ?

Comment: If $\lim_{z \to \infty} f(z) = f(\infty)$ and for $g(z) = 1/z$ we have that $(f \circ g)(z)$ is analytic at the origin

Comment: Unclear. The $\phi_j$ are charts of our Riemann surface. $f$ is analytic because for all $j$ for all $a\in U$ there is some $i$ such that $\phi_i^{-1} \circ f\circ \phi_j$ is analytic at $a$ in the usual sense.

Comment: If you are affraid by the operations with $\infty$ and divisions by $0$ then $\phi_i^{-1} \circ f\circ \phi_j$ must be analytic at $a$ or have a removable singularity.